# Searching in two collections

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, collections

I have two collections. A collection of BindingSource and a collection of DataSet. Now I try the corresponding data types of the BindingSource collection to found in the table types of the DataSet collection. But my approach is slightly elegant. How could I solve it using LINQ?

```
foreach (var bindindSource in view.DataContext)
{
    var dataSource = bindindSource.DataSource;
    string sourceName = ((Type)dataSource).Name;

    foreach (var dataSet in model.DataSource)
    {
        var table = (from DataTable t in dataSet.Tables
                     where ((Type)t.GetType()).Name.Equals(sourceName)
                     select t).FirstOrDefault();
        if (table != null)
        {
            bindindSource.DataSource = table;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>` up front mapping table type names to tables?

Comment: millimoose, sorry, what I would win with this solution?

Comment: I would personally caution against thinking that [elegance lies in making the code as short as possible](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97912).  Your code looks simple, readable, and nothing seems unnecessary or duplicated.  What are you seeking to improve about it?

Comment: @peter70 For one you'd go down a complexity level. As it is you're iterating over the list of tables for every dataset. Secondly: it matches what you're doing better. You're looking for a `DataTable` by its name, but telling this is the case requires parsing three lines of code. It makes sense to keep a mapping of names to `DataTables`, and reduce the LINQ query to a dictionary access. This should also get rid of the ugly `foreach`/`break` combination. (Actually you should always get rid of that by extracting the loop into a function that `return`s something.)

Comment: @peter70 The dictionary would be built using something like `var tablesByName = (from set in model.DataSource from table in set.Tables select table).ToDictionary(table => (table.GetType() as Type).Name)`, and the rest of your code *should* reduce to `foreach (var source in view.DataContext) { source.DataSource = tablesByName[(source.DataSource as Type).Name]; }`. Give or take actually testing if I get the intent of your original code right, and error handling. (I.e. using `TryGet` instead of `[]` if you expect some table names to be missing, or handling duplicate names.)

Comment: Also, a general rule of thumb is that LINQ will not make code prettier if that code doesn't involve a lot of temporary collections.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you very much! The only problem that remains perhaps is, if there are different tables with the same name. But that changes nothing, that your solution is good ;-)

Comment: @peter70 Right, I'll answerify it then. (Didn't feel like doing so up front since I can't really test if it does what your original code does and it's a pretty big change.)

Comment: It does what it should do. Now, this is the result of your idea: var tablesDictionary = (from set in model.DataSource from DataTable table in set.Tables select table).ToDictionary(table => (table.GetType() as Type).Name);  foreach (var bindingSource in view.DataContext) { var key = (bindingSource.DataSource as Type).Name; if (tablesDictionary.ContainsKey (key)) { bindingSource.DataSource = tablesDictionary[key]; } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to associate a `BindingSource` to the first `DataTable` with the same `Type` name. The straightforward approach would be to prepare a `Dictionary` up front that maps the names you're using for the lookup to the tables:

```
var tablesByName = (from set in model.DataSource 
                    from table in set.Tables 
                    select table) // get all tables of all sets
                   .ToDictionary(table => (table.GetType() as Type).Name)
```

(If the tables never change, this can be a `static` field that's only computed once.)

Then the rest of your code should reduce to:

```
foreach (var source in view.DataContext) 
{
    DataTable table;
    var name = (source.DataSource as Type).Name;
    if (tablesByName.TryGetValue(name, out table))
    {
        source.DataSource = table;
    }
}
```

I've omitted handling things like there being tables with duplicate names. (Which would make `ToDictionary()` fail, so you have to get rid of duplicates before that call.)